# calculating kmer nucleotide frequency per column

Tags: python, sequence-analysis, k-mer

I have a list of sequences:

```
CAGGTAGCC
CCGGTCAGA
AGGGTTTGA
TTGGTGAGG
CAAGTATGA
ACTGTATGC
CTGGTAACC
```

Each sequence is nine nucleotides long. I want to calculate the dinucleotide frequency of AA, CG ..etc for each of the dinucleotide positions.
Similar problem shared with one nucleotide in this [post](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/3089/calculating-nucleotide-frequency-per-column).

For example, 1st two column will have these bases CA,CC,AG,TT etc, and second two should be AG,CG,GG,TG and so on. Output should be something like this

```
AA   0.25    0.34    0.56    0.43    0.00    0.90    0.45    0.34    0.31
CC   0.45    0.40    0.90    0.00    0.40    0.90    0.30    0.25    0.2
GC   0.00    0.00    0.34    1.00    0.30    0.30    0.35    0.90    0.1
TC   0.24    0.56    0.00    0.00    1.00    0.34    0.45    0.35    0.36
```

AA, CC, GC and TC could be any dinucleotide combination.

**What I tried from the last post: mainly taken from @Devon**

```
import itertools
hl = []

#making all possible dinucleotide combinations
bases=['A','T','G','C']
k = 2

kmers = [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(bases, repeat=k)]
kmers = dict.fromkeys(kmers, 0)
print(kmers)
for i in range(9):
    hl.append(kmers)

# my seq file
f = open("H3K27ac.seq")
nLines = 0

for line in f:
    id = 0
# trying to read dinucleotide at each loop
    for (fst, sec) in zip(line[0::2], line[1::2]):
        id = id + 1
        hl[id][fst+sec] += 1
    nLines += 1
f.close()

nLines = float(nLines)
for char in ['AA', 'TT', 'CC', 'GG', 'CG', 'GC']:   
    print("{}\t{}".format(char, "\t".join(["{:0.2f}".format(x[char]/nLines) for x in hl])))
```

By somehow it's estimation the total count of all dinucleotide in whole file.
I am trying to make it more general so that it can be used for tri- and any further number of nucleotides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. The following code works for any aligned character set, but assumes that all sequences should be the same length.

```py
import itertools

      
with open("f.txt") as seqs:
    sequences = list(line.strip() for line in seqs.readlines())

# Just in case sequence lengths are different
n = min(len(s) for s in sequences)
if any(n != len(s) for s in sequences):
    print("Sequence lengths are different!")

# Get all bases. 
bases = set(c for seq in sequences for c in seq)

k = 2 
kmers = [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(bases, repeat=k)]
pos_to_freq = []

for i in range(n - k + 1):
    kmers_dict = dict.fromkeys(kmers, 0)
    for s in sequences:
        kmers_dict[s[i:i+k]] += 1/len(sequences)
    pos_to_freq.append(kmers_dict)

for kmer in kmers:
    print("\t".join([kmer] + [str(round(d[kmer], 3)) for d in pos_to_freq]))
```

Output for your example is below (I apologize for the formatting):

```
AA  0   0.143   0   0   0   0.143   0   0
AT  0   0   0   0   0   0.286   0   0
AC  0.143   0   0   0   0   0   0.143   0
AG  0.143   0.143   0.143   0   0   0.143   0.286   0
TA  0   0   0   0   0.571   0   0   0
TT  0.143   0   0   0   0.143   0.143   0   0
TC  0   0   0   0   0.143   0   0   0
TG  0   0.286   0.143   0   0.143   0   0.429   0
CA  0.286   0   0   0   0   0.143   0   0
CT  0.143   0.143   0   0   0   0   0   0
CC  0.143   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.286
CG  0   0.143   0   0   0   0   0   0
GA  0   0   0   0   0   0.143   0   0.429
GT  0   0   0   1.0 0   0   0   0
GC  0   0   0   0   0   0   0.143   0.143
GG  0   0.143   0.714   0   0   0   0   0.143
```

Comment: Works perfect with python3. Many thanks